# Generic Swift Protocol inside Generic Controller

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, type-alias, associated-types

Is it possible to have generic inside generic?

I have this protocol

```
public protocol ListViewModelProtocol {
    typealias ViewModel
    typealias Cell

    func titleForHeaderInSection(section: Int) -> String?
    func numberOfSections() -> Int
    func numberOfRowsInSection(section: Int) -> Int
    func viewModelAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ViewModel
}
```

I also have base `ListViewModel` that implements this protocol

```
public class BaseListViewModel<T, U> : ListViewModelProtocol  {
}
```

But already here it says that my `ListViewModelProtocol` is not implemented. How can I set T and U to be of specific class inside protocol? Because if I write this in protocol

```
typealias ViewModel: CustomClass
typealias Cell: CustomCell
```

Its still not working.

My goal is to subclass `BaseListViewModel` like

```
public class TestListViewModel : BaseListViewModel<TestCellViewModel, TestTableViewCell> { 
}
```

Then I could just do this in my `BaseViewController`

```
public class BaseViewController<T: ListViewModelProtocol>: UITableViewController  {
}
```

And in some subclass `ViewController` do this:

```
public class CustomViewController: BaseViewController<TestListViewModel>  {
}
```

and that way `CustomViewController` would "get" `TestCellViewModel` and `TestTableViewCell` (actually its BaseViewController).

But of course this is not working as I expected. What am I missing? Or I have to define `typealias` for `ListViewModelProtocol` in every class that implements it or uses it as generic type? Which means I would have to define `ViewModel` and `Cell` of `ListViewModelProtocol` in both `BaseListViewModel` class and `BaseViewController` class, but thats not so generic since I just want to put base types of those in protocol and thats it.

Or maybe there is something wrong with my approach and I should implement this differently?

Any suggestions are useful. Thanks

**EDIT**

I have managed to fix this but I have another problem.

```
    public class BaseViewController<T: ListViewModelProtocol>: UITableViewController  {
         var dataSource: T?
    }
```

This datasource is used inside UITableViewDataSource methods by calling its own methods (see ListViewModelProtocol methods). Everything is working fine but when some custom controller:

`Controller: BaseViewController<TestListViewModel>`

is being deinitialized I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. If I put

```
deinit {
    self.dataSource = nil
}
```

it works but I would like to know why I need to set it to nil.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

typealias keyword has more than one meaning ...

```
// protocol can't be generic
protocol P {
    // here typealias is just placeholder, alias
    // for some unknown type
    typealias A
    func foo(a:A)->String
}

// C is generic
class C<T>:P {
    // here typealias define the associated type
    // in this example it is some generic type
    typealias A = T
    func foo(a: A) -> String {
        return String(a)
    }
}

let c1 = C<Int>()
print(c1.foo(1))     // 1

let c2 = C<Double>()
print(c2.foo(1))     // 1.0

// D is not generic!!!
class D: C<Double> {}

let d = D()
print(d.foo(1)) // 1.0
```

Update, to answer the question from discussion

```
class Dummy {}

protocol P {
    // here typealias is just placeholder, alias
    // for some inknown type
    typealias A : Dummy
    func foo(a:A)->String
}

// C is generic
class C<T where T:Dummy>:P {
    // here typealias define the associated type
    // in this example it is some generic type
    typealias SomeType = T
    func foo(a: SomeType) -> String {
        return String(a)
    }
}

class D:Dummy {}
let c = C<D>()
print(c.foo(D())) // D
```

and

```
// now next line doesn't compile
let c1 = C<Int>() // error: 'C' requires that 'Int' inherit from 'Dummy'
```

Comment: is there a way to put a constraint on typealias A to be subclass of something in P protocol?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a protocol with associated types you have to set these associated types in the your generic implementation:

```
public class BaseListViewModel<T, U> : ListViewModelProtocol  {
  typealias ViewModel = T
  typealias Cell = U

  // implement the methods as well
}
```